# Coordinates of the truncated 120 cell

Tags: geometry, polyhedra

I'm looking for the coordinates of the truncated 120 cell. They are given at the bottom of this page: http://eusebeia.dyndns.org/4d/trunc120cell

However when I use these coordinates I don't get the expected result. More likely I did a mistake, but I'd like to double check with another reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They seem correct here. When I construct a polytope with the specified permutations of the given coordinates in [polymake](https://polymake.org/), I get a polytope which is isomorphic to the truncated 120-cell produced by `wythoff("H4", range(0,1))`. Polymake reports that they are not congruent, but I think they are similar, up to rounding errors. All the edges are of uniform length (2 with the coordinates given at your link, as compared to $\sqrt{2}$ with Wythoff's construction in polymake).

Make sure you're getting all the right permutations. You will get $4\cdot 16 = 64$ vertices each from the first three points given, $12\cdot8=96$ vertices each from the next five points (the ones including 0), and $12\cdot16=192$ vertices each from the remaining nine points, for a total of 2400 vertices.